# parse a xml and unset the nodes

Tags: xml

How to parse a xml and get the nodes.

Comment: What have you tried? And your tags are confusing - what does node.js have to do with things?

Comment: tried json_decode() ?

Comment: use decode json and a recursive tree iterator

Answer (score 1):

You could use `json_decode` to decode the string, an recursive function to delete all inactive elements and finally `json_encode` revert the array to an json string

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$json['categoryTree'] = filter_inactive($json['categoryTree']);
echo json_encode($json);

function filter_inactive($data) {
    $t = array();
    foreach ($data as $child) {
        if ($child['is_active'] == '1') {
            if (isset($child['children'])) {
                $child['children'] = filter_inactive($child['children']);
            }
            $t[] = $child;
        }
    }

    return $t;
}
```